# How to force symfony form to only display and accept positive integers?

Tags: twig, constraints, symfony4, symfony-forms

I have the following code:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Positive;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('x', IntegerType::class, [
            'mapped' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'constraints' => [new Positive()]
            ])
}
```

The twig form is as follows:

```
{{ form_widget(form.x, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
```

However, the rendered form (HTML) still allows users to input values with a minus sign.
How do I change that, so the rendered form forbids minus sign and stops at 1 on the arrow input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to add the [HTML5 `min` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-min-and-max-attributes) for that, which you can add at the definition of your form field:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Positive;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('x', IntegerType::class, [
            'mapped' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'constraints' => [new Positive()],
            'attr' => [
                'min' => 1
            ]
        ])
}
```